# Python folder contents CSV writer

Tags: csv, python-3.x, command-line, directory, directory-structure

I'm trying to make a simple command line script with Python code that generates a CSV when it scans the contents of a directory, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, cause I keep getting errors. Can someone tell me what the heck I'm doing wrong?

```
import sys
import argparse
import os
import string
import fnmatch
import csv
from string import Template
from os import path
from os.path import basename
header = ["Title","VersionData","PathOnClient","OwnerId","FirstPublishLocationId","RecordTypeId","TagsCsv"]
if not sys.argv.len < 2:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = header, delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()
        if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[2]):
            for d in os.scandir(sys.argv[2]):
                row = Template('"$title","$path","$path"') #some default values in the template were omitted here
                writer.writerow(row.substitute(title=basename(d.path)), path=path.abspath(d.path))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat, csvwriter.writerow(row) takes only one argument. You need to wrap your arguments inside brackets and then join with comma.

Moreover, you cannot call other functions within the row object, which is what you are trying to do with row.substitute(args) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone else needing a quick CSV listing of folders, here's the code I got to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, os, csv
from string import Template
from pathlib import PurePath, PureWindowsPath
from os.path import basename

header = ["Title","Path","","","","",""] # insert what header you need, if any
if not len(sys.argv) < 2:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writeheader()
        initPath = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin') or sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
            p = PurePath(initPath)
        else:
            if sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
                p = PureWindowsPath(initPath)

        if os.path.isdir(str(p)) and not str(p).startswith('.'):
            for d in os.scandir(str(p)):
                srow = Template('"$title","$path", "","","",""')
                #s = srow.substitute({'title': basename(d.path), 'path': os.path.abspath(d.path)) #
                #print(s) # this is for testing if the content produces what's expected
                row = {'Title': basename(d.path), 'Path': os.path.abspath(d.path)} # the dictionary must have the same number of entries as the number of header fields your CSV is going to contain.
                writer.writerow(row)
```